# No resource found that matches the given name, even though its not supposed to be there

Tags: android

So this is my activity.xml and it is showing me a errornd

```
No resource found that matches the given name (at 'text' with value '@string/hello_world').
```

I dont have @string/hello_world anywhere one my activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button 
            android:id="@+id/press_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/press_button"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my Strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">GpsLocater</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="press_button">Press Button</string>

</resources>
```

When you create a activity it automatically put hello world in strings and in the activity but I got rid of it so what is the error this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove R.java in the gen directory in your project. It should recreate R.java. It should be fine then.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your project, restart IDE.